# Problems with Workbech Moderation states

Tags: workbench

I'm using Workbech Moderation module. I need to moderate some types of content. 
The problem that I've is that after change the moderation state to Publicate ("Publicado"), it doesn't change the state.

This are the transitions that I've:

[image]

I need 3 states, Publicate("publicado"), Needs Revision ("Necesita revisión") and Archivado Legal.

I've a menu link to see all the nodes that needs revision. With a [menu badged](https://drupal.org/project/menu_badges), that counts the nodes that needs revision.

After moderate the node and change the state to "Publicado" the menu badged decreases, but if I go to "find content" menu link, I can see that is not publicated.

[image]

If I edit the node I can see that the moderation state is "Draft".

[image]

If I delete Draft state from the Workbench moderation state configuration, I can see that the nodes moderation state is empty.

[image]

This is a bug? If it isn't, what can I do?

I hope somebody can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One point - editing a node will always set the state to draft. This is how workbench is meant to work. When you edit, you create a new revision which stays in draft form until you publish it.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that even I change the node from Draft to Needs revision, and the to publish, it dosn't change the state to publish. The node is Draft. You can see this process in the pictures

Comment: What do you see if you visit the node directly at its view page? Is it shown as draft there?